# Worklight server is working but html page doesn't show

Tags: java, jetty, ibm-mobilefirst

I downloaded the Worklight Studio from IBM's page. And created an application, but the MyWLApp.html page doesn't show anything. It should be write 'MyWLApp', but it doesn't show. By the way I started the Worklight server, and on the application right click/run as/run on server, for show the html page, but it gives :

> web page can not be found

Also I was change the port of Worklight from Eclipse.in and set it 8085. When I change the web page to localhost:8085 it gives :

```
HTTP ERROR: 404
Problem accessing /MyWLApp/MyWLApp.html. Reason: 
    ProxyServlet: /MyWLApp/MyWLApp.html
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Powered by Jetty://
```

Comment: Have you looked over Module 3 from here - https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started/index.html ? It should outline how to preview your application in the third section.

Answer (score 2):

Right click on app and select build and deploy. This will start WL server.

Comment: i don't even see that option in 'Run as'
so i had to manually set my run configurations. but still it doesn't work

Comment: ok, i found that build all and deploy option after opening the apps folder and right clicking on the name of my application.